# ApacheDS - Search by email address fails unless 'mail' attribute is manually updated after initial creation

Tags: apache-ds

We are running ApacheDS 2.0.0.AM25 running on Windows 2019.  The directory is for S/MIME email certificates.

Users are populated from an eDirectory driver as ObjectClass=person, ObjectClass=organizationalPerson, and ObjectClass=inetOrgPerson.  Attributes for each user are CN, mail, sn, usercertificate;binary

Checking the ApacheDS log, the user objects are successfully created.  I verify the new objects using Softerra LDAP Administrator, they look correct and all attributes populated correctly.  There are no leading or trailing spaces in email address in the 'mail' attribute.

When attempting a lookup using LDIFDE, searching an exact email address (bob.test@abc.com) returns no results. If any character in the email address is manually updated (uppercase to lowercase; Bob.test@abc.com), the search then is successful.

The 'mail' attribute has been set to be indexed.  I do not know if this is a cache issue or some other problem. Has anyone experienced a similar issue?